# Why does iter() borrow the list as immutable?

Tags: rust

In [*Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists*](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/second-iter.html), the `iter()` creates an iterator:

```
impl<T> List<T> {
    pub fn iter(&self) -> Iter<T> {
        Iter { next: self.head.as_ref().map(|node| &**node) }
    }
}
```

I try to test if the iterator prevents further modification on the list:

```
let mut list = List::new();
list.push(1);

let mut iter = list.iter();
list.pop();
```

The compiler reports an error:

```
list2.rs:114:1: 114:5 error: cannot borrow `list` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable [E0502]
list2.rs:114 list.pop();
             ^~~~
list2.rs:113:24: 113:28 note: previous borrow of `list` occurs here; the immutable borrow prevents subsequent moves or mutable borrows of `list` until the borrow ends
list2.rs:113         let mut iter = list.iter();
                                    ^~~~
```

It seems that Rust would indeed prevent unsafe operations, but from the syntax, why does `list.iter()` borrow the `list`? In the method, it just return the reference of the head element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the linked article:

```
pub struct Iter<T> {
    next: Option<&Node<T>>,
}
```

So the iterator has a reference.  Expanding to make the lifetime more explicit:

```
pub struct Iter<'a, T> {
    next: Option<&'a Node<T>>,
}
```

Now looking at the `iter` method:

```
impl<T> List<T> {
    pub fn iter(&self) -> Iter<T> {
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm leaving out the implementation for clarity, since Rust's borrowing rules stop at the declaration too.  Now if we put the elided types back in:

```
pub fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> Iter<'a, T> {...}
```

Since there is only a `&self` argument, the return value gets the same elided lifetime.  See the [elided lifetimes documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html).

The end result is that the `Iter<'a, T>` has the same lifetime as the reference passed to the `iter()` method - so that reference's lifetime must be extended to at least as long as the `Iter` object's.  Therefore you can't borrow mutably (for the `pop` method) while the `Iter` is alive.

There is a good reason for this; if the `pop` were to succeed, the iterator would then have a dangling reference to the former head, leading to memory unsafety.