# error[E0502]: cannot borrow `char_array` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

Tags: rust

I am writing a small program to identify the first recurring character in a string:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut main_string = String::new();

    println!("Please enter the string : ");
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut main_string)
        .expect("Failed to read the input value");

    main_string = main_string.trim().to_string();
    println!("The trimmed string is : {}", main_string);

    let repeating_character = recurring_string_parser(main_string);

    println!(
        "The character which is first repeating is {}",
        repeating_character
    );
}

fn recurring_string_parser(main_string: String) -> char {
    let mut char_array = Vec::new();
    for each_char in main_string.chars() {
        let mut some_val = char_array.iter().find(|&&c| c == each_char);

        match some_val {
            Some(ch) => return each_char,
            _ => println!("do nothing"),
        }
        char_array.push(each_char);
        println!(" The charcater is {:?}", some_val);
    }

    return 'a';
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `char_array` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:31:9
   |
25 |         let mut some_val = char_array.iter().find(|&&c| c == each_char);
   |                            ---------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
31 |         char_array.push(each_char);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
32 |         println!(" The charcater is {:?}", some_val);
33 |     }
   |     - immutable borrow ends here
```

What is it that I am doing wrong? It would be of great help if someone could explain it as well because I am finding it difficult to grasp the concept of mutable borrowing.

Comment: `char_array` isn't what its name suggests. (i.e., it's not a `Vec<char>`)

Comment: That was a mistake I had overlooked but now it is corrected, but that was not causing the problem.

Comment: Actually, I contest that it *was* causing the problem, since [adding `.cloned()` (or, equivalently, `.map(|r| *r)`) fixes it.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c7654bb8f0ff9572b15e4a72d93202f5&version=stable) (As Shepmaster's answer also observes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `char_array.iter().find(|&&c| c == each_char)` is an `Option<&char>`; a reference pointing at the original item in `char_array`. You then attempt to modify `char_array` which could invalidate any references. After that, you try to access the now-potentially-invalid value by printing it.

In a language like C or C++, this code would be allowed but would occasionally crash, corrupt data, allow for arbitrary code execution, or eat your laundry.

The laziest solution is to reorder the `println` and add an extra set of braces around where `some_val` should live. (In the future we will have *Non-Lexical Lifetimes* and the extra braces won't be needed):

```
{
    let mut some_val = char_array.iter().find(|&&c| c == each_char);

    match some_val {
        Some(ch) => return each_char,
        _ => println!("do nothing"),
    }
    println!(" The character is {:?}", some_val);
}

char_array.push(each_char);
```

You could also clone the value, breaking the relation between `some_val` and `char_array`:

```
let mut some_val = char_array.iter().find(|&&c| c == each_char).cloned();
```

See also:

- [Unable to borrow an iterator as mutable more than once at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26920789/155423)
- [Why does iter() borrow the list as immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38166580/155423)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. Your solution worked!!!